# Como fazer uma borda inferior a 1px?

Tags: css

Tem como fazer uma borda com CSS inferior a 1px? Pois no meu layout ficou muito grosso.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quando eu estou com problemas no pixels do `border`, ao invés de definir `1px solid black`, eu uso `thin solid black`.

Veja (Dê um zoom no navegador pra notar a diferença):

```css
.px-border{
    border:1px solid black;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}

.thin-border {
   border:thin solid black;
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="px-border"></div>
<div class="thin-border"></div>
```

Veja o resultado com 500% de zoom no navegador Google Chrome:

[image: Thin solid black deixa bem "magrinho"]

Quando você define valor `thin` ("fino" em português), você está definido que o tamanho da borda será o mínimo possível.

Esse valor pode ser definido em separado na propriedade `border-width`, `border-left-width`, `border-right-with`, `border-top-width` e `border-bottom-width`.

Note que uma diferença entre `thin` e a propriedade definida em pixels é que, visivelmente, a definição em píxels acompanha o zoom do navegor, já o `thin`, não.

Comment: Excelente dica o `thin` ajuda bastante, é possivel notar alguma vantagem com telas de retina ou smarthphones, apesar de caso a caso. +1

Comment: Com certeza a melhor resposta. Obrigado amigo

Answer (score 14):

Antes de mais nada, importante considerar estas duas situações:

- Numa configuração normal em monitor convencional (HD ou menor), `1px` é um "quadradinho" na tela, não tem como pintar metade dele. Seria como você perguntar "como acendo só metade da lâmpada do meu abajur?"
- Num monitor HI-DPI a coisa já fica um pouco diferente. Os navegadores agrupam vários pixels formando um "pixel lógico" maior, então existe o "meio pixel". Só que como quase a especificação CSS para estes casos é inconsistente, não há um meio seguro de usar este "meio pixel" diretamente com CSS. Seria necessário usar imagens para produzir esta borda, o que mudaria essencialmente a estrutura do código (e só teria efeito em monitores de alta densidade).

O que dá pra fazer de maneira bem mais simples, é simular espessura menor usando uma aproximação, com transparência ou cálculo de cor intermediária:

[image: 1 pixel] [image: "meio" pixel]

A imagem da esquerda tem um pixel branco como espaço. Como era espaço demais, na da direita foi "simulado" um espaço menor usando um cinza em vez do branco original, dando ilusão de espaço menos.

Aplicando este mesmo conceito no `border` com CSS:

```css
div {margin:10px;width:150px;float:left}
br {clear:both}
#pxA2 {border-bottom:2px solid rgb(255,200,0);}
#pxA1 {border-bottom:1px solid rgb(255,200,0);}
#pxAM {border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,200,0,.5);}
#pxB2 {border-bottom:2px solid #FC0;}
#pxB1 {border-bottom:1px solid #FC0;}
#pxBM {border-bottom:1px solid #FE9;}
```

```html
<br>Com transparência:<br>
<div id="pxA2">2</div>
<div id="pxA1">1</div>
<div id="pxAM">+-.5 (simulado)</div>
<br>Com cores:<br>
<div id="pxB2">2</div>
<div id="pxB1">1</div>
<div id="pxBM">+-.5 (simulado)</div>
```

Como você pode perceber, está longe do ideal, mas pode minimizar um pouco o problema da "grossura" da linha.

A idéia é que a linha mais "fina" tenha uma cor correspondente a uma porcentagem da cor original, e uma porcentagem da cor de fundo.

No exemplo 1, a cor é a mesma `255, 0, 0`, mas no "meio pixel" usamos .5 no *alpha* (transparência):

```
#pxA1 {border-bottom:1px solid rgb(255,200,0);}
#pxAM {border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,200,0,.5);}
```

No exemplo 2, fizemos a tal "transparência" manualmente, a cor original é `FC0`, o fundo é `FFF`, então o 1º `F` se manteve, o 2º ficou entre o `C` e o `F` (usamos `E`), e o terceiro entre `0` e `F`, então usamos `9` (não usei cálculos exatos, só aproximei para facilitar).

```
#pxB1 {border-bottom:1px solid #FC0;}
#pxBM {border-bottom:1px solid #FE9;}
```

(créditos do Pikachu ao @GuilhermeNascimento, que "pixelizou" o original)

Comment: +1 pela arte, +50 em breve pela resposta :)

Answer (score 11):

Não. Não tem como fazer algo com menos de 1px, a princípio um pixel é a menor unidade de medida pra renderizar algo na tela.

Você pode tentar fazer alguns truques usando transparência, uma cor menos intensa vai dar essa impressão de ser "mais fina".

```css
div { border-color: blue; border-style: solid; margin: 2px; }

div.b1 { border-width: 1px; }
div.b2 { border-width: 0.1em; }
div.b3 { border-width: 0.01em; }
div.b4 { border-width: 1px; border-color: rgb(160, 160, 255); }
```

```html
<div class="b1">Borda 1</div>
<div class="b2">Borda 2</div>
<div class="b3">Borda 3</div>
<div class="b4">Borda 4</div>
```

Você pode criar uma cor para este truque, [neste site](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/color-blend). Veja um exemplo com a borda vermelha.

```css
div { border-color: #FF0000; border-style: solid; margin: 2px; }

div.b1 { border-width: 1px; }
div.b2 { border-width: 0.1em; }
div.b3 { border-width: 0.01em; }
div.b4 { border-width: 1px; border-color: #FF8B8B; }
```

```html
<div class="b1">Borda 1</div>
<div class="b2">Borda 2</div>
<div class="b3">Borda 3</div>
<div class="b4">Borda 4</div>
```

Baseado [numa resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13891295/4190610)

Comment: Se desse eu daria +3... Ótima reposta.

Comment: Dá um voto na original também :p Aí já são +2

Comment: Apesar de achar as demais respostas excelentes, eu concordo mais com a sua, pois a sensação de borda grossa é provavelmente devido a cor de maior contraste, ou seja não é a borda que esta grossa e sim o contraste que pode estar excessivo +1.